# How do I delete a Panopoly landing page?

Tags: 7

I was able to disable the page by going to `admin/structure/pages` then clicking **Disable**. However, I am not sure how to **delete** the landing page.

**Note**: I am running Panopoly on Pantheon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Patrick Kenny for the information. I prefer not to "hack" as it does cause difficulty updating.

### My Solution

On `admin/structure/pages/edit/mypagename`I clicked the **Delete** tab that appeared after disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is provided by a module, it is saved as part of the module's code.  You cannot delete the page from the UI, only disable it.  If you really wanted to delete it, you could hack the module's code and delete the lines that provide the landing page, but this is likely to cause problems down the line when you try to update Panoply.

I would just disable the page and leave it at that.  End users will never see it if it is disabled.